# ru_RU Оффлайновое распознавание речи (SpeechToText)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, распознавание-речи, xamarin.android

Распознавание речи в оффлайне не работает с русским языком,но работает со всем остальными.Все словари скачаны.

xiaomi redmi 3s android 6.0 - api 23 google search последней версии

```cs
var recListener = new RecognitionListener();

recListener.BeginSpeech += RecListener_BeginSpeech;
recListener.EndSpeech += RecListener_EndSpeech;
recListener.Error += RecListener_Error;
recListener.Ready += RecListener_Ready;
recListener.Recognized += RecListener_Recognized;

Recognizer = SpeechRecognizer.CreateSpeechRecognizer(this);
Recognizer.SetRecognitionListener(recListener);

SpeechIntent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech);
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguageModel, RecognizerIntent.LanguageModelFreeForm );
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraCallingPackage, PackageName);
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ActionRecognizeSpeech,RecognizerIntent.ExtraPreferOffline  );
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputPossiblyCompleteSilenceLengthMillis, 1500);
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraSpeechInputMinimumLengthMillis, 15000);
SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraMaxResults, 1);

string str;
str = "ru_RU";
//Java.Util.Locale.Default.ToString();

SpeechIntent.PutExtra(RecognizerIntent.ExtraLanguage, str);
```

Представленный код все время выдает ошибку SpeechRecognizer.Error.SERVER

Подскажите, может кто-то знает причины...

Answer (score 0):

Подтверждаю, тоже самое. То ли после обновы апликухи "google" перестало работать, то ли после перехода на 23 API именно русский офлайн словарь перестал работать, хотя скачен.